# Limit of Convergent Sequences in a Compact Graph when the Domain is Compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $f: E \to N$ where $E$ is compact. The graph of $f$ is:
$$
G(f)=\{(x,f(x)):x\in E\}
$$
Also, assume that $G$ is compact.

Consider $(x_n) \subseteq E, (x_n)\to x$ and the corresponding sequence $(x_n,f(x_n)) \subseteq G$. Since $G$ is compact, pick a subsequence:
$$
(x_{n_k},f(x_{n_k})) \to (x,a)
$$

**Question:** Is $a=f(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(x,a)\in G(f)$ you have, by definition of graph, that $f(x)=a$.

Comment: What if $a=f(x')$ where $x' \neq x$?

Comment: @ASlowLearner cannot happen, because then $(x,a) \notin G(f)$. As $G(f)$ is compact the subsequential limit must be a point of $G(f)$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you!

Comment: Notice that we do can have $f(x')=f(x)$ for $x'\neq x$, but it just means that $f$ is not injective. As @HennoBrandsma said, compacity of $G(f)$ implies $(x,a)\in G(f)$ and that's all we need to conclude $f(x)=a$.

Comment: Note that we also assume limits are unique (so we're in a Hausdorff or metric space), in general we have $(a,b) \in G(f)$ with $(x_{n_k}, f(x_{n_k}) \to (a,b)$ and then $x_{n_k} \to a$ and also $x_{n_k} \to x$ so $x=a$ if limits are unique. Also $b = f(a)$ from $(a,b) \in G(f)$, so $b=f(x)$.

Comment: And I meant "compactness" instead "compacity", sorry about that